# Twig only finding namespaced bundle names in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am just upgrading from Symfony 2.0 to 2.5. I have a problem rendering a template from within a controller in bundle let's call it DemoBundle:

```
$this->render("AcmeDemoBundle:Index:index.html.twig");
```

Twig is looking for AcmeDemoBundle but only knows the namespace `@AcmeDemo`.

So when I change my controller code to the following, it works:

```
$this->render("@AcmeDemo/Index/index.html.twig");
```

Why is twig only understanding the namespaced bundle name and not the full name?

Did I miss something in the Twig Config? I am running PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: did you tryed if the @Template Annotation is working ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html

Comment: Yes I tried using @Template Annotation in the Controller Action and Twig is still not able to find my Template File. I guess the problem lies in the call Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate(AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig). Because Twig only knows the namespace "AcmeDemo" it cannot map "AcmeDemoBundle" and is looking for the file in the __main__ Namespace.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that Twig is actually finding the template file but it is searching at a different location when using namespaced template name vs. not namespaced. My web user has no read access at the location. This must be caused by some symbolic links in my Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. In the console I called `php app/console cache:clear` from a path where the webapp user had no read permissions to. Because twig cached some config files containing these absolute paths it couldn't read the templates when executed as webuser.